# Array Sorting: Creating games for a sports event

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a problem that I have been thinking about, but I can't really figure out how to solve it. I am writing software for my local sports club, which has an international tourney coming up soon. I would like to have the administration as automised as possible. I have done a great deal already, but now I'm struggling to get one last thing done.

Say, you have an array with 4 teams, namely team A, B, C and D. What I would like to do, is to create a new array, with all possible games. That isn't so hard to do, but the difficulty lies in the fact that I would like to have some sort of sorting capability in it. The way I have it now, the games are created like this:

```
['A - B', 'A - C', 'A - D', 'B - C' , ...]
```

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
['A - B', 'C - D', 'A - C', 'B - D', 'A - D', ...]
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve this? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sidenote: A - B = B - A, We don't need a two-way competition (but I can program this bit myself if necessary).

Comment: What's your exact requirement when ordering the games? No team plays two games one right after the other? Is the number of teams fixed (4)?

Comment: No team plays two games after each other and the number of teams is not fixed (could be 5, could be 6, ...) that's the part that is making it extra difficult :)

Comment: Is there a requirement that restricts the maximum number of games that a team does NOT play between two games of the team?

Comment: Well, the idea is that every team plays almost as much games within a certain amount of time (so if team A has played 3 games, team D should have played two or 3 games aswel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.
it is shown below :)

```
function sort_array($teams)
{
    $num_teams = count($teams);
    if(count($teams)%2 != 0)
    {
        $ghost = array();
        $ghost["name"] = "ghost";

        array_push($teams, $ghost);
        $num_teams++;
    }

    $games = array();
    for($i = 1; $i < $num_teams; $i++)
    {
        if($teams[$i]["name"] != "ghost")
                array_push($games, $teams[0]["name"] . " - " . $teams[$i]["name"]);

        for($k = 1; $k <= $num_teams; $k++)
        {
            $index_team_1 = ($i+$k < $num_teams) ? $i+$k : $i+$k-$num_teams;
            $index_team_2 = ($i-$k > 0) ? $i-$k : $i-$k+$num_teams-1;

            $temp_add = array();
            $temp_add["team_1"] = $teams[$index_team_1]["name"];
            $temp_add["team_2"] = $teams[$index_team_2]["name"];

            if($teams[$index_team_1]["name"] != "ghost" && 
                $teams[$index_team_2]["name"] != "ghost" &&
                $index_team_1 != 0 &&
                $index_team_2 != 0 &&
                $temp_add["team_1"] != $temp_add["team_2"] &&
                !in_array($temp_add["team_1"] . " - " . $temp_add["team_2"], $games) &&
                !in_array($temp_add["team_2"] . " - " . $temp_add["team_1"], $games))
                {
                    array_push($games, $temp_add["team_1"] . " - " . $temp_add["team_2"]);
                }
        }
    }

    return $games;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple problem more of a MATRIX problem and the result is the diagonals

$teams[0...n]

```
$index=0;
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    for($c=$i+1;$c<$n;$c++)
        $matches[$index++]=$teams[$i]." - ".$teams[$c];
}
```

Now $matches is ultimately a matrix of matches
To sort it:

```
$sorted_games //You should pass on the matches diagonally and skipping one when possible
```

A B C D

> AB---AC---AD
>
> -------BC---BD
>
> --------------CD

Their indices are

> 0---1---2
>
> -----3---4
>
> ----------5

Pass diagonally and skip when possible:

0 then 5 (we skipped 3)

now go inside to 1

so 0 - 5 - 1

Now we do not skip (because not on main diagonal so we take 4)

so 0 - 5 - 1 - 4

We continue inside to 2

so 0 - 5 - 1 - 4 - 2

Finally we go back to main diagonal and get the 3

so Result is 0-5-1-4-2-3

and the matches are : AB - CD - AC - BD - AD - BC

Comment: I'll try this now, but it looks logical! ;) Thanks for the answer

Comment: this looks great, but how exactly do I program the iteration in the diagonals? :)

Comment: i was trying to find a way :( but am at work at the office :S  I really think it is simple ):

Comment: no sweat. if you would come up with a way, could you let me know? :)